# How to find the number of subsequences with GCD=1 using BOTTOM-UP DP approach?

Tags: c++, recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization, greatest-common-divisor

I came across a question where we are given with a sequence of numbers, and we have to find the number of subsequences with gcd=1.

```
Eg:    
2 3 5 7   
count: 11    
6 10 15    
count: 1
```

I have solved this question using the top-down approach by the recurrence relation in which we either consider the element or not which goes like -

```
func(position,current_gcd) = func(position+1,current_gcd) + func(position+1,GCD(curr_gcd,element[position]) ;
```

Can someone please suggest a tabulation or bottom-up approach for the same..?

Comment: can you please provide some constraints? like the maximum length of the given sequence and the maximum possible value of each element in the sequence

Comment: The question consists of T test cases (1 ≤ T ≤ 100) and each test case consists of N numbers(1 ≤ N ≤ 60). The max value for each element of the seq is 10^4.